# change the color of the button on click event

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have an html button that when the user clicks the button it will change color from blue to red and back. Is there a better way to do this in jQuery?

```js
clicked = true;
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("button").click(function() {
    if (clicked) {
      $(this).css('background-color', 'red');
      clicked = false;
    } else {
      $(this).css('background-color', 'blue');
      clicked = true;
    }
  });
});
```

```css
button {
  background-color: blue;
  height: 100px;
  width: 150px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>Press</button>
```

Comment: if you make the css a class (instead of the button tag), then you could use  toggleClass("class");

Comment: Define "better way"

Answer (score 1):

One way you could do this is add a class for the red background color and toggle that class:

```js
$("button").click(function(){
  $(this).toggleClass("redButton");
});
```

```css
button{
    background-color: blue;
    height:100px;
    width:150px;
}
.redButton { background-color: red; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>Press</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

Using jquery and toggleClass:

```js
$("button").click(function(){
  $('.btn').toggleClass('toggled');
})
```

```css
.btn{
   background-color: blue;
      padding: 10px;
      color: white;
  }
.toggled{
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<button type="button" class="btn">Press</button>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use toggle class function for that like this

```js
clicked = true;
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $("button").click(function(){
                    $(this).toggleClass('red');
                    $(this).toggleClass('blue');
                  
            });
        });
```

```css
button{
       
        height:100px;
        width:150px;
    }
    
    .red
    {
    background-color:red;
    }
    
    .blue
    {
    background-color:blue;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Button Fun</title>
        <script src = 'bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js'></script>
        <script type="home.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css"/>
      
    </head>
    <body>
    
        <button class="blue">Press</button>
    
    </body>
    </html>
```